# Is there any value related to a time series pattern?

Tags: information-theory, signal-processing, time-series, pattern-recognition

I've been digging a little into signals and I just started a networks and telecommunications class at college. We saw there are different encode techniques Amplitude, Frequency and Phase shift keying (ASK, BFSK and BPSK). Using this techniques one can form different patterns in a signal to encode information, a "message".

I want to know if there is any numerical value that can be related to a signal pattern, to the "message" this pattern encodes. For example, if I have 2 signals with different information encoded in eachone (using the same encoded techniques and standards), is there any measure I can get from this signal, that can show the patterns are different?

I am quite new at this topics and I haven't had any luck in books and papers, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Of course not.  There are more signals than there are values for any given metric.  There are infinitely many signals that bear the same information... to take just one example.